# How to pass value from asp to aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I am in asituation ,where i have to redirect from asp to aspx page with parameter.I tried a lot of option,but the redirection is working ,but i couldnt the value in my aspx.cs page.

Below is my asp

```
Dim objASPError,strRemoteIP
Set objASPError = Server.GetLastError
```

**The below is not working with parameter**

```
'Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
'Response.AddHeader "Location", "/404.aspx?    err="+objASPError
'Response.End
```

I even tried by setting the hiddenn value and accessed the form element in aspx.cs

```
document.getElementById("hdnErr").value=objASPError
```

The below is also not working with objASPError

```
response.Redirect("/404.aspx?err="&objASPError)


<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="404.aspx">
<input type="hidden" id="hdnErr" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My aspx.cs

```
Label lbl = new Label();
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    string message=string.Empty;
        if(Request.Form["hdnErr"] != null)
        {
             message = Request.Form["hdnErr"].ToString();
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["err"] != null)
        {
            String temp = Request.QueryString["err"].ToString();
            lbl.Text = temp;
        }
```

Thanks

**Question** 
 I understand sending the values through querystring is not a best option ... How to send error object from asp to aspx..

Comment: UPDATE response.redirect("/404.aspx?err=" & objASPError.ASPDescription) is working.. before i was passing the whole object ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnErr" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnErr" />
```

Also, Server.GetLastError returns an object so you can't combine it with a string. Take a look at the example in the msdn doc.

[ASPError Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524942%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank u .. but not working... the following line is working              'response.redirect("/404.aspx?rezCode=M01006")..problem is while attaching the runtime value as response.Redirect("/404.aspx?err="&objASPError)